# Can you reproduce this strange #SPILL! ? Can you explain it?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dynamic-arrays

In cell `B3` I put this RANDARRAY :

```
=RANDARRAY(3,5,1,20,1)
```

to test a small LET to generate UNIQUE values across an array:

```
=LET( array,B3#,
       aCols, COLUMNS( array ),
       eSeq, SEQUENCE( ROWS( array ) * aCols,, 0 ),
       UNIQUE( INDEX( array, eSeq/aCols + 1, MOD( eSeq, aCols ) + 1 ) ) )
```

that I put in `H3`.

When it calcs, it spills a list of unique values from the array *(whereas UNIQUE generates an either row-wise or column-wise)*.

All good, but I notice that when I calc *(F9)*, it occasionally returns #SPILL!. ***(and there was nothing in the rows underneath that would force a #SPILL!(***

So, I trapped when it does this and copied the values to a new range and ran the formula on just those values. The #SPILL! does not happen.

Then I put the formula `=B3` into `J3` and copied it across to make a new array of cells that simply looks at each cell in the B3# array and I made a copy of my LET formula and placed it in `P3` with **array** set to `J3:N5`.  Then I hit F9 until the #SPILL! recurred.

It happens quite frequently - about 15% of the time.

Usually, the #SPILL! happens on both arrays (B3# and J3:N5), but every so often it happens to only one of the two copies:

Happens to J3:N5

[image]

Happens to B3#

[image]

Most of the time, it happens to both:

[image]

Any idea why?

Can anyone reproduce this?

#### Source of the problem, but no explanation

[P.b.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12634230/p-b) proposed in the comments this (much better) formula. It exposed that the root of the problem comes from UNIQUE in combination with a Random input. So I have now tried `=UNIQUE(RANDARRAY(15,1,1,20,1))` and found that it has the #SPILL! problem.

What is also interesting is that this formula can be placed in multiple cells and all of them tend to #SPILL! simultaneously even though they would have independent inputs. These result in #SPILL! about 95% of the time if more than one is in a workbook.

Here I have a dozen of them - only one succeeded and that was after hitting F9 about 10 times.

[image]

Comment: Yup, definitely weird.  I get the same.  Not sure why.  The only thing I can think of is that it is a bug, that the old value does not clear fast enough and the next iteration "sees" values in those cells?

Comment: I can also reproduce this.

Comment: thanks @ScottCraner and BigBen. I had this happen before in a formula that does a similar manipulation now that I think about it. It looked at a column of values and repeated each value by a matching array of number values. e.g., `{"a";"b";"c"}` would be repeated by `{1;2;3}` to yield `{"a";"b";"b";"c";"c";"c"}`. This is mechanically very similar as it is multiplexing an array with indices via INDEX. In any case, annoying.

Comment: I, too, can repro, and I have no idea why it is occurring.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - I may test to see what is the minimal component to create the error. If you remove UNIQUE, it does not happen. If you use UNIQUE without INDEX, it does not happen.

Comment: I reproduced it on the app version as well. I also tried a different approach which involves less calculation: `=UNIQUE(LARGE(A20#,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A20#))))` but that's also instable: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XcDu.jpg

Comment: Normally a #Spill! Shows a blue frame from where to where the formula tries to spill it's result, but that's not the case.

Comment: @P.b - your formula spills in sync with the other formulas. I took your (excellent and better than my) formula and replaced SEQUENCE with `=UNIQUE(LARGE(B3#,{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15}))`. It has the same SPILL problem. I then pointed your formula at an array of 1 random number and 14 fixed values. It randomly #SPILLS!. This narrows it down to UNIQUE in combination with a RAND input as the source of the problem. If that's the case, I would rarely need to do this with a RAND target, so this glitch will not impact me and now I have an even better UNIQUE array formula - thanks to you.

Comment: I split your test formula across two cells; so `=RANDARRAY(15,1,1,20,1)` and `=UNIQUE(A1#)`. The result is that only the Unique cell ever shows an occassional SPILL# error, so the issue is with Unique. Not sure what the fix is...

Comment: Hey @Tragamor - funny, I was in my car and wondering why `=UNIQUE(RANDARRAY(15,1,1,20,1))` throws #SPILL! 99% of the time while `=UNIQUE( reference to some range with RAND... )` throws it 10 to 20%. I didn't think to do what you have done to test it. I turned in a bug report to MSFT.